# Which textbox events fire when a value is being set from the ViewModel (MVVM)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

I need to apply a format to the Text property through code behind in a custom control, i.e. intercept the value and format it. I cannot use `StringFormat`**.

I am looking for an event that will fire when the value is being set from the VM so I can intercept the value there.

**I am using `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` and this doesnt work as expected with `StringFormat`

Comment: How about the TextChanged event?

Comment: Is the property two way? If so how will you handle the discrepancy at the VM end?

Comment: I don't think your approach is right tell us what format you need .... using converter is something that you can think off

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer its two way.

Comment: Nooooooooooooope.  Well, NOPE if you are using a UserControl.  Expose your text property on the surface of the control as a DependencyProperty.  Bind against that.  Now, listen for changes to that property in your UC and, when they happen, update your UI.  Blam, done.

Answer (score 1):

Custom controls don't generally map to a VM, or expose their templates directly for binding. Do you mean a UserControl?

If it really is a custom control, then you should expose a dependency property on your control for the VM to bind to. Then inside your control template you can bind the textbox to it too via a converter.

Answer (score 0):

for requirements like these I would recommend you to have a converter

```
Text="{Binding YourTextValue, Converter={StaticResource FormatConverter}}"
```

and converter as -

```
Public Class FormatConverter
    Implements IValueConverter


    Public Function Convert(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.Convert
        Return ' your formatted string
    End Function

    Public Function ConvertBack(ByVal value As Object, ByVal targetType As Type, ByVal parameter As Object, ByVal culture As CultureInfo) As Object Implements IValueConverter.ConvertBack
        ' do nothing. or may be if you want to
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Was worried about having to set the converter on all instances, because I am currently doing this on a custom control. I think this may work, if I put the converter on a Style. thanks

Comment: yea make a style and apply to all